# PIXI - disabled preventDefault touch events not working on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, canvas, mobile

Since I´m working on a project where I need to be able to drag objects around my canvas but also to scroll the entire page by dragging the actual canvas 'background' behind my PIXI Sprites, i followed the findings of this guy here:

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/2483 :

> By default, the Pixi canvas/display-area cannot be used to scroll the
>   webpage that contains it. Which is important on touch screens. (eg. If
>   you use the rest of the web-page to pinch-zoom into the Pixi canvas,
>   you can become trapped and unable to zoom back out (or pan away),
>   because there's no non-Pixi-canvas area of the page to "grab" with
>   your pinch gesture).
>
> To enable this functionality, I use autoPreventDefault. But this comes
>   with some undesirable side-effects, like scroll/pinch-zoom actions
>   over the canvas registering "taps" or clicks in a way that doesn't
>   make sense. (ie. I'm attempting to zoom or scroll the outer page at
>   that point, not interact with the Pixi canvas)
>
> To work around that, I modify and compile my own custom version of
>   Pixi where I can apply preventDefault in a more granular way...
>
> To get page-scrolling functionality it seems I only need to
>   preventDefault in the InteractionManager.prototype.onTouchEnd
>   function. Whereas autoPreventDefault will also preventDefault on 3
>   other events. (onMouseDown, onTouchMove, onTouchStart).
>
> Leaving autoPreventDefault = false and applying preventDefault only to
>   onTouchEnd, gives me the functionality I need. But it'd be nice to not
>   have to customize and rebuild Pixi in this way every release. (Sorry
>   if there's something else I'm missing here; I don't completely
>   understand the event system in Pixi, or what else to do about this
>   scroll-touch problem)

So i disabled e.preventDefault() on 'onTouchStart' and on 'onMouseMove' but left it as is on 'onTouchEnd'

This works perfect on IOS devices but not on Android, the only exception being a Samsung A7 using Adblock browser (fails on Chrome).

Would really appreciate some help on this.

TLDR:

Disabling PIXI´s e.preventDefault on onTouchStart and onMouseMove works on IOS devices and lets me scroll the page by draggin my canvas around but not on Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for that was to use

```
renderer.plugins.interaction.autoPreventDefault = false
```

This should work on iOS and Android.
Docs for autoPreventDefault reads:

> Should the manager automatically prevent default browser actions.

Using PIXI 4.5.6. 
Take a look at the docs: 
http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.CanvasRenderer.html#plugins
http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `renderer.plugins.interaction.autoPreventDefault=true` should do the trick.